# Jetty 8 configuration with JSR-356(websockets)

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I want to ask if Websockets configuration in jetty 8 can not be done through annotations like we do in jetty 9. Jetty 9 has both JSR-356 implementation and its own implementation.
I was referring this http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-websocket-example/.

Question is can we use annotations to configure websockets in jetty 8. If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), and only supported Servlet 3.0.

It never had support for JSR-356 (javax.websocket)

[Jetty 9.1.0 added support for JSR-356](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00060.html) as part of its Servlet 3.1 finalization.